# I want to access my VM from multiple users, So how can i create the multiple user access?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I need 2 users to access the same VM at the same time.
Can anyone please tell me, how to create multiple users and how to give access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps below are the minimum amount of work to achieve what you ask for. Of course if the server is part of a shared environment you will have to think about securing it at the very least by setting good passwords.

*Do not expose the Remote Desktop functionality directly to the Internet or you are likely to have a bad time.*

**Enabling Remote Desktop**

Remote desktop will let two users use a server simultaneously.
In Server Manager select the Local Server tab, find the Remote Desktop property, Click where it says "Disabled" and click the radio button next to "Allow remote connections to this computer". Ensure the checkbox to "Allow connections only from computers running (...) [NLA]" is checked.

**To create a user**

In Server Manager, select Tools -> Computer Management.
When the program starts, select Local Users and Groups, then Users.
Right-click in an empty area of the user list and select New User.
Fill in the fields.

**To allow users to access the computer**

You should learn enough about the software the server will run to give users the minimum necessary privileges. It's good to make a habit of using groups for this rather than giving individual users explicit rights.

The minimum rights to access a computer via Remote Desktop is given by selecting the Groups view, double-click the Remote Desktop Users group and add the accounts to it.